# Type error: K is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I am getting a weird error, I am trying to receive data from a html form but I get this error:

> Type error: K is undefined

My JavaScript function is:

```
function setVal(oForm, name) {
  var setdefvalue = 1;
  oForm.elements[name].value = setdefvalue;
}
```

And my HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/setVal.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="page-top" class="index" onload="setVal(document.forms[0], 'pages');">
    <form>
      <span name="pages"></span>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a sample of the area that's giving me the error.

Comment: Please include your error message.  Better yet, use Stack Overflow's built in java snippet tool to build a complete, verifiable reproduction of the problem.

Comment: If you're just starting out, can I strongly advise you to use any of the common bracing and indentation files and **not** the style shown in the question, which is hard to read and hard to edit (in particular, adding statements to the block is unnecessarily complicated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your element is a `span`, not a form field such as an `input` or `textarea`. `span` elements are not included in the `elements` collection on forms, only form fields are. `span` elements also don't have a `value` property (again, only form fields do). And `name` is not a valid attribute for [`span` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (but is for form fields).

Comment: does that mean even elements contained in <span> can't be accessed?

Comment: @j0nimost: No. The `elements` collection includes all of the fields in the form, regardless of whether the fields are direct children or deeper descendants. For instance, if you had `<span><input type="text" name="pages"></span>`, your code would work to set the field of that text field.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i feel like you should add that bit of comment to the answer for it to be complete :)